# How to define $L^{\infty}$ norm for vector-valued functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

for functions $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\| f-g\|_{\infty} := \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}}\|f-g \|$.
But if now we have $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}$,
How do we define $\|f-g\|_{\infty}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $h\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is bounded, there exist $M>0$ such that $\|h(x)\|\leq M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus we can define
$$\|h\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \|h(x)\|$$
as usual (analogously for essentially bounded functions).

---

More generally, if $X$ is a set and $Y$ is a normed vector space, a bounded function $h\colon X\to Y$ has norm
$$\|h\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in X} \|h(x)\|_Y$$